# Jade-style blocks in Ruby templates (Haml?)

Tags: ruby, haml, pug

is there any template engine in Ruby which supports something like Jade `extend` and `block` (https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#template-inheritance)? This is an awesome feature, compared with the simple `:layout` option that Haml and similars support.

Any ideas how to implement these blocks in Ruby? Maybe extend Haml's syntax?

Comment: If I understood the feature correctly, a similar effect could be achieved in Rails using [content_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use **content_for?** and **yield** in haml for template inheritance.
Example:

Base.html.haml

```
    %html
        = render "layouts/head"
            %body
                .container.container-main
                    = content_for?(:page_content) ? yield(:page_content) : yield
```

Now you can use 'page_content' from another haml =>

Derived.html.haml

```
    - content_for :page_content do 
        /contents
```

Anything in the 'content_for :block_name' block gets executed in the context of it's respective yield in the layout.